# Getting 404 error while accessing component of another application inside a folder on server in angular 5?

Tags: angular, routes, angular5, angular4-router

I am working on angular 5 application.

I have created an application with multiple components and routes, When I try to access the component directly from the server with folder name then it return 404 error.

I have a folder on server with name 'testapp' and in this folder I have uploaded the build of my angular 5 application. In my angular 5 application I have 2 components with route /main & /main1, so when ever I try to access 'main' component with url: servername/testapp/main then it return 404 error in route.

Comment: Your server should redirect any url to the index.html of your app. You're getting a 404 because those files don't exist outside of the app. The app is just one page and takes care of the routing itself.